# Is it possible to undeploy an WSO2 app with the editor?

Tags: wso2, siddhi

Is it possible to undeploy an siddhi/wso2 streaming app using the browser editor?
I see an option to deploy an app but nothing for undeploying it

[image]

I was able to manually undeploy by going into the worker docker container and deleting the application file in **/wso2sp-4.4.0/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot undeploy a siddhi app from the editor, but you can stop a running app in the editor profile with the stop button.

In order to undeploy an app from the worker, you have two options.

1. Delete the app from the deployment directory.
2. Use the Siddhi Application Management [APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP440/Siddhi+Application+Management+APIs) to delete the app.